# Enabling different features depending on iOS version

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, version

In the application we're building, we want to use UILocalNotifications, which are only available from 4.0.

Checking if an object responds to a selector is pretty easy, but how can I go about defining delegate methods on a class depending on the OS? The problem I get is that my app delegate implements the

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

method, which makes the application crash on startup on a iOS 3.2 device (ipad).

Not having to release multiple builds would be preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a feature called “weak linking,” which will work with iOS 3.1 or later. There are some very specific steps you need to follow, which are outlined in the 4.2 [“what's new” document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS4.html) (search for “weak linking” in the document).

HTH!

Answer (score 3):

One nice way is to check this:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_4_0 // if iPhoneOS is 4.0 or greater then __IPHONE_4_0 will be defined

    //code
#endif
```

If you're dealing with an OS below 4.0, if won't even see any code within that compiler directive.

Comment: Thanks, but won't using #ifdef simply strip out the code from compilation if the target is less than 4.0?

Comment: sure, but don't you need to strip that method out, if the device is less than 4.0?

Comment: Indeed, but then I probably need multiple targets for the different iOS versions, right?

Comment: If you set your iOS Deployment Target (in the Build tab in Target Settings) to the lowest SDK you're using, and Base SDK to the highest, the compiler actually takes care of all possible branches. I have an app with the same problem as you, and this method works great for both devices using the same target. Give it a try!

Comment: If it's working for you I'm pretty sure it's because of the weak linking support described in other answers.  The preprocessor will always include the code for iPhone 4.0 if the base SDK is set to 4.0 or higher, no matter what deployment target is set.  There are not really "multiple paths" to code because there are no paths for an instance creation, there are just the types that make up the various method declarations and instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

Marco Arment has a recent post about it, with good insights:

[Supporting older versions of iOS while using new APIs](http://www.marco.org/1648550153)

Answer (score -1):

You could change the delegate methods to use `id` as the type for classes not available on 3.2, that is:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(id)notification
```

In the method body, check for UILocalNotification as usual. The `notification` argument can be typecast to UILocalNotification.

I'm surprised this causes a crash though, since the method shouldn't be getting called. If changing the type in the method definition doesn't help, it may be that the method is getting called for some reason. In that case try setting a breakpoint in the method to find out why.

Comment: Referencing the class will cause GCC to include it in the app's symbols and cause it to crash at runtime if the symbol is not found. You need to follow some specific rules to make weak linking work.